# Размещение изображения в canvas (js)

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Как можно сделать так, чтобы в canvas загружалась картинка либо из мануально указанного url, либо из выпадающего списка?
фрагмент кода html:

```
<select id="image-select">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="http://www.captionite.com/templates/good_guy_greg.jpg">Good guy Greg</option>
                <option value="http://www.captionite.com/templates/scumbag_steve.jpg">Scumbag Steve</option>
                <option value="http://www.captionite.com/templates/high_expectations_asian_father.jpg">High Expectations Asian Father</option>
            </select>
```

js начала изучать совсем недавно и многое еще непонятно.
вот сырой фрагмент кода js:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = document.getContext("2d");

var getImage = function(){
  var selectList = document.getElementById("image-select");
  var source = selectList.options[selectList.selectedIndex].value;
  var img = new Image ();
  img.src = source;
};

img.onload = function() {
// Work out where to center it
x = canvas.width/2 - img.width/2;
y = canvas.height/2 - img.height/2;

// Draw it
context.drawImage(img, x, y);
};

getImage();
img.onload();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка 1: контекст канваса должен задаваться самому канвасу, а не документу, то есть вместо

`var context = document.getContext("2d")`

должно быть

`var context = canvas.getContext("2d")`

Ошибка 2: определение `img` происходит внутри функции `getImage`, хотя по коду `img` используется при загрузке страницы, но его нет, вследствие чего возникает ошибка.

Ошибка 3: при загрузке страницы изначально выбранная опция `select` - пустая, картинку загружать неоткуда. Вместе с тем, в коде нет отлавливания изменений выбранной опции, а значит при выборе другой картинки она не может загрузиться.

Вот пример с использованием jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/bz4wgyqq/

На чистом javascript-е: http://jsfiddle.net/0n6bz4cx/